# Is my proof of $|a| \leq b \iff -b \leq a \leq b$ correct?

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

### Background

Hello, I'm teaching myself proofs, and am unsure whether or not my proof of $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}(|a| \leq b \iff -b \leq a \leq b)$ is correct.  Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

### Proof

*Proof*.  $(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $ |a| \leq b$.  We consider both cases.

**Case 1.**  $a \geq 0$.  Then $|a| = a \leq b$ by definition of absolute value.  Since $a \geq 0$, then $-a \leq 0$ by multiplying the inequality by $-1$.  Similarly, multiplying $a \leq b$ by $-1$ gives us $-a \geq -b$, or equivalently $-b \leq -a$.  Since $-a \leq 0$ and $a \geq 0$, or equivalently $0 \leq a$, then $-a \leq a$ by transitivity.  We now have the following inequality,

$$
-b \leq -a \leq a \leq b
$$

Which means $-b \leq a \leq b$ by transitivity.

**Case 2.** $a < 0$.  Then, $|a| = -a \leq b$ by definition of absolute value.  Multiplying both sides of the inequality by $-1$, we get $a \geq -b$, or equivalently, $-b \leq a$.  Since $-b \leq a$ and $a < 0$, then $-b < 0$.  Also, since $-b < 0$, multiplying by $-1$ means $b > 0$, or equivalently $0 < b$.  But since $a < 0$, then $-a > 0$.  By transitivity, $a < 0 < -a$, means $a < -a$.  Note that $-a \leq b$.  So we have,

$$
-b \leq a < -a \leq b
$$

$\color{blue}{\text{I am unsure about this part.  How do I introduce equality?}}$ Therefore, $-b \leq a < -a \leq b$.  Since $a < 0$ and $-a > 0$, the only time $a = -a$ is when $a = -a = 0$.  So,
$$
-b \leq 0 \leq b
$$

Or, $-b \leq a \leq b$ by substitution.

Since we've exhausted all cases, if $|a| \leq b$ then $-b \leq a \leq b$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $-b \leq a \leq b$.  Then, $a \geq -b$ and $a \leq b$.  We must show $|a| \leq b$.  We consider two cases.

**Case 1.** $a < 0$.  Multiplying $a \geq -b$ by $-1$, we get $-a \leq b$.  By definition of absolute value, $-a = |a| \leq b$.

**Case 2.** $a \geq 0$.  Since $a \leq b$, then $a = |a| \leq b$ by definition of absolute value.

Therefore, $|a| \leq b$ when $-b \leq a \leq b$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.  $\qquad \Box$

### Question

I'm really self-concious about my ability to do this sort of stuff, so I hope I haven't butchered this.  The blue highlighted part is where I'm most uncertain.  I've seen some books (e.g. Rosen's Discrete Math book), use the following definition for absolute value:

$$
|a| = a \text{ when } a \geq 0 \text{, and } -a \text{ when } a \leq 0.
$$

In other words, he uses the $\geq$ and $\leq$ relations in both cases.  Is this okay? I've always seen the definition as $a < 0$ for one case, and $a \geq 0$ for the other.  Does this matter?  If it does, how do you introduce the equality like I had to for Case 2 in the $(\rightarrow)$ proof?  Also, when using transitivity, and you have something like
$$
-b \leq a < -a \leq b
$$

I'm guessing you can't conclude $-b \leq a \leq b$.  Since we haven't established that $a = -a$, so we can't say more than what we're given, which is that $a < -a$, so we could only say $-b \leq a < b$.  Is my reasoning correct here?

Comment: Both definitions are equivalent. $2\lt 5$ and $2\le 5$ both statements are true. In particular, in your case, $|a|=0 $when $a=0$ so defining $|a|$ for $a\le 0$ and $a\ge 0$ is correct.

Comment: Here's a small nitpick: if you're going to prove that $0 \le a \implies -a \le 0$, you can do this by adding $-a$ to both sides. Similarly $a \le b \implies -b \le -a$ by adding $-(a + b)$ to both sides. I prefer this argument because it is usually taken as more fundamental that $a \le b \implies a + c \le b + c$, for any $c$. However, this is probably not relevant to what you're doing, and the point I'm really trying to make is that usually when you're proving things about the reals you can just say things like "Since $0 \le a$, we have $-a \le 0$" without further justification.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I see.  I was wondering if I could get away with a less "rigorous" proof with something like what you mentioned in your last sentence.  So it seems this is acceptable then.  I'm not quite sure I understand your nitpick though.  Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Aaron, all I was saying that in my opinion, it's a bit more "obvious" to say that if $0 \le a$, then clearly for any $c \in \Bbb R$, we have $0 + c \le a + c$. So taking $c = -a$, this gives $-a \le 0$. Your approach is obviously correct, but with my suggestion you basically assume less about the reals. *If* you're going to prove that $0 \le a \implies -a \le 0$, then multiplying both sides by $-1$ is kind of assuming what you want to prove, whereas this is more of a proof from more basic principles. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field#Total_order also.

Comment: I should emphasise that this really is a huge nitpick though. The part I'm talking about isn't really that relevant to your proof. As I said earlier, I'd estimate that in most contexts you can just leave it out, maybe unless you're doing certain exercises very early on in an analysis course. I think generally your proof looks very very good, especially for someone who's just learning. I can see that you pay a lot of attention to detail. Keep it up!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you for the clarification and for the compliment and encouragement.  I want to be aware of nitpicky stuff like that.  What would I read/study to become more acquainted with the reals? An analysis book? What subject deals with these ideas?

Comment: Yes, I'd say this comes under elementary real analysis. I haven't ever really learned maths from a book so I'm afraid I can't tell you if that's a good idea or not :) My very vague advice is to just do things you find interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two definitions of absolute value are equivalent. Some would argue that the one that you’re using is better style, because the cases are disjoint, but the one that you found in Rosen is also acceptable, since the two parts of the definition agree when both apply, i.e., when $a=0$.

There is no need to introduce equality after you arrive at

$$-b\le a<-a\le b\;:\tag{1}$$

that immediately implies that $a<b$, and if $a<b$, then **certainly** $a\le b$, so from $(1)$ you can immediately conclude that $-b\le a\le b$.

I would probably have organized the proof of $(\leftarrow)$ a little differently, doing **Case 2** first, since it’s truly trivial: if $a\ge 0$, then $|a|=a$, and we’re assuming that $-b\le a\le b$, so $-b\le|a|\le b$. That, however, is a matter of taste.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was a fantastic explanation.  A couple questions.  Regarding the first point, $-b \leq a < -a \leq b$ implies $a < b$ which means $a \leq b$.  This holds because of the disjunction correct? Meaning $a < b \lor a = b$.  The reason we can say $a \leq b$ is because we know one disjunct is true, which makes the whole statement true.  Is this the reasoning here?

Comment: The second question is regarding your statement on $(\leftarrow)$.  I can see why it's incomplete.  Here was my approach that led me to leave that off.  Since we assume $-b \leq a \leq b$, I separated the conjuncts into $a \geq -b \land a \leq b$.  I thought that when doing a proof with a conjunction in the hypothesis, by simplification I can separate them and just use one of them.  Do I need to use both conjuncts?

Comment: @Aaron: You’re very welcome! Yes, that’s correct: $a\le b$ is effectively the disjunction of $a<b$ and $a=b$, so either of them implies $a\le b$. No, you don’t need to use both conjuncts; my objection was that your argument never actually established that $-b\le|a|$.

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not sure I understand why we have to prove $-b \leq |a|$.  Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Aaron: Oops! You’re right: I’d lost track of what you were proving. Let me fix my answer.